# Get sales email set in configuration on template

Tags: magento2, blocks, template, scopeinterface

In a custom module I'm trying to get store information set on the Admin panel in a template.

I've been able to get it for most by adding get functions such as the below, but can't get the one for the sales email.

```
public function getPhone()
{
    return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
        'general/store_information/phone',
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
}

public function getSalesEmail()
{
    return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
        'general/ident_sales/email',
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
}
```

Any idea's what I should do, I think the parameter `'general/ident_sales/email'` is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go it, it needed to be:

```
public function getSalesEmail()
{
    return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
        'trans_email/ident_sales/email',
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
}
```